# Skip request restsharp

Tags: c#, restsharp

a question about restsharp. How can I skip receiving a request? that is, there is a mandatory sequence of requests. I have to send a request but not get a response. The problem is this request loads a heavy page, and I don't need it. client.execute.skip??

Answer (score 0):

Use timeout .

```
    var client = new RestClient(BaseUrl);
    client.Timeout = 10000; // 10000 milliseconds == 10 seconds
```

or u can extend like this

https://exceptionnotfound.net/extending-restsharp-to-handle-timeouts-in-asp-net-mvc/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).